# unable to load a haskell module

Tags: regex, haskell, haskell-stack

Using stack version 1.9.3 and
GHCI version 8.6.3, I follow these steps:

- create a new project with `stack new "myproject"`
- `cd` into myproject
- run `stack install regex` which returns the following

> base-compat-0.10.5: using precompiled package hashable-1.2.7.0: using
>   precompiled package time-locale-compat-0.1.1.5: using precompiled
>   package utf8-string-1.0.1.1: using precompiled package
>   regex-base-0.93.2: using precompiled package
>   unordered-containers-0.2.9.0: using precompiled package
>   regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35: using precompiled package
>   regex-tdfa-1.2.3.2: using precompiled package regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.3:
>   using precompiled package regex-1.0.2.0: using precompiled package
>   Completed 10 action(s).

At this point I assume the regex package is correctly installed.

But then in my code when I try to import the regex package with `import Text.RE` I get the following error

> Could not load module ‘Text.RE’ It is a member of the hidden package
>   ‘regex-1.0.2.0’. You can run ‘:set -package regex’ to expose it.
>   (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.) Use -v to
>   see a list of the files searched for.

What am I missing out on ?

Comment: You probably need to edit the generated cabal file of your project to add `regex` as a dependency.

Comment: If you are using stack you probably have a `package.yaml` file, from which the `xxxxx.cabal` file is generated. You can edit the `package.yaml` file to add the dependency, so that `stack build` should work.

Comment: The second suggested question ("How do I add...") addresses the point about `package.yaml` mentioned by chi.